# How to create custom header which hides and shows on scroll, like Facebook app

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-animation, flutter-sliver

I'm trying to replicate a custom header, above a ListView, which hides and shows when the user scrolls the list. Very specifically, I want it to behave like the **Facebook** app... as soon as the user scrolls down, the header slides up out of view. Then, no matter how far down the list you are, when you scroll back up the header slides back into view immediately.

I've been playing with various **Slivers**, **AnimatedContainers** etc, but I can't get this exact behaviour.

**SliverAppBar** seems the closest, but it seems to have a predetermined structure, and I can't see a way to make it completely customizable.

**SliverPersistentHeader** and **SliverToBoxAdapter** both seem to remain fixed in place, and don't reappear when you scroll back up.

Any ideas on now to achieve this please?

Comment: make `floating` parameter `true` and `pinned` parameter `false`

Answer (score 0):

I made something like this a while ago but only with a searchbar as the content of the `SliverAppBar` and because the `SliverAppBar` needs a predetermined size to be built I used a work-around like this.

```
class _ListScreenState extends State<ListScreen> {
  final GlobalKey _flexibleSpaceBarKey = GlobalKey();
  late Size sizeFlexibleSpaceBar;
  bool _visible = true;

  getSizeAndPosition() {
    RenderBox _cardBox = _flexibleSpaceBarKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
    sizeFlexibleSpaceBar = _cardBox.size;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) => getSizeAndPosition());
    Future.delayed(Duration(microseconds: 1)).then((value) {
      setState(() {
        _visible = false;
      });
    });
  }

  Widget _copyFlexibleSpaceBar() {
    return Visibility(
      visible: _visible,
      key: _flexibleSpaceBarKey,
      child: _buildSearchbar(),
    );
  }

  Widget _buildSearchbar() {
    return Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        horizontal: 24.0,
        vertical: 12.0,
      ),
      child: MyCustomSearchBar(),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Example-Title'),
        elevation: 0.0,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          children: [
            _copyFlexibleSpaceBar(),
            if (!_visible)
              Expanded(
                child: NestedScrollView(
                  headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) =>
                      <Widget>[
                    SliverAppBar(
                      pinned: true,
                      floating: true,
                      toolbarHeight: 0.0,
                      expandedHeight: sizeFlexibleSpaceBar.height,
                      elevation: 4.0,
                      flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                        background: _buildSearchbar(),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                  body: Container() // Your content
                ),
              ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

(Not sure if it works because I copied it from my git-repo and changed/removed some stuff)

So what I did there was, to build my custom header and immediately make it invisible, thus I can get the actual size and can use it to build the `SliverAppBar`.

I have to add, this idea is not mine, I got it from another post which I can't find right now.

Hope it somehow helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, this looks interesting... I know you said it may not work, but I'm trying my best to get it running, however I get the error 'LateInitializationError: Field 'sizeFlexibleSpaceBar' has not been initialized.'. I'll continue to look at it, but if you have any idea how to get around that I would appreciate it!